# Function Returns unwanted value when a Negative values is passed to function q/kdb

Tags: kdb

The function should return the same negative value as it is passed to it

Comment: Can you give details as to what exactly you want the function to do? There are likely simpler (and built-in) ways to achieve what you want

Comment: list of strings made of inputs col with comma seperators for 1000s to left of decimal point and numDecPlaces digits to right @terrylynch
If i pass a negative value with 15 decimals Eg: [enlist -0.229;15], it should return as same negative value as passed to it but as string Eg: "-0.029"
I need a if condition to with the negative values and to return as string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't quite get your code to work as-is but I can tell that your problem with negative numbers is because you're using `floor` and `floor` doesn't give you the correct "before decimal" components when it comes to negative numbers:

```
q)floor -0.331 1234.56 1.2345 18908.46 1234561 -1233.544
-1 1234 1 18908 1234561 -1234
```

A naive solution using your same function might be to do something like:

```
?[col>0;FormatNumber[col;5];"-",/:FormatNumber[abs col;5]]
```

There is likely a cleaner way to do this using either `.Q.f`, `.Q.fmt` or `-27!`. Alternatively this approach uses just string manipulation (likely only works well for small numbers, e.g. stock prices)

```
q)prettyPrintNums:{"."sv'@'[;0;{reverse","sv 0N 3#reverse x}]"."vs'neg[0|-[;y]count'[s]-1+s?\:"."]_'s:string x};
q)prettyPrintNums[-0.331 1234.56 1.2345 18908.46 1234561.0 -1233.544;2]
"-0.33"
"1,234.56"
"1.23"
"18,908.46"
"1,234,561"
"-1,233.54"
q)prettyPrintNums[-0.331 1234.56 1.2345 18908.46 1234561.0 -1233.544;5]
"-0.331"
"1,234.56"
"1.2345"
"18,908.46"
"1,234,561"
"-1,233.544"
```

Comment: i want to check for the condition if negative values passed to Formatnumber[-0.229;15], then it should return the same negative value with 15 decimal places casting as string. @terrylynch

Comment: Does my idea above not do that? `?[col>0;FormatNumber[col;5];"-",/:FormatNumber[abs col;5]]`. Also I don't think you're going to be able to get 15 decimal places.....your logic is casting to long and you're very likely to hit numbers greater than the maximum long when you do `"j"$(10 xexp DecimalPlaces)*col-floor col`

Comment: ''''?[col>0;FormatNumber[col;5];"-",/:FormatNumber[abs col;5]]''' i'm trying to insert as conditional statement like if the values FormatNumber[enlist -0.229;15] since negative value is passing to it then it check for condition col<0 the move to ''''?[col>0;FormatNumber[col;5];"-",/:FormatNumber[abs col;5]]'''  else if its positive  value should pass through remaining code

Comment: That snippet of code already does that! `?` is an if-else. If values are positive it passes into existing function, if they're negative it takes absolute value and passes through the function and puts a minus sign in front. Have you tested that snippet of code?

Comment: the code snipped works fine individually @TerryLynch. But there is error occured Mismatched types while i placed the code in FormatNumber function. My requirement to place the code snippet` ?[col>0;FormatNumber[col;5];"-",/:FormatNumber[abs col;5]]` in the FormatNumber function itself. 
can you help me mentioning the code snippet in my FormatNumber function or suggest me writing the function call like `FormatNegativeNumber:[col;numDecimal]{?[col>0;FormatNumber[col;5];"-",/:FormatNumber[abs col;5]]}` from FormatNumber else a code snippet using .Q.f. or .Q.fmt

Comment: Your idea could work: `FormatNegativeNumber:{[col;numDecimal] ?[col>0;FormatNumber[col;numDecimal];"-",/:FormatNumber[abs col;numDecimal]]}`

Comment: i'm trying to incorporate in the `FormatNumber` Function but not able to do it. getting errors like mismatched types. can you` {[col;numDecimal] ?[col>0;FormatNumber[col;numDecimal];"-",/:FormatNumber[abs col;numDecimal]]}` this in the same Function code `FormatNumber` instead of writing a new function `FormatNegativeNumber` can you incorporate same in my code mentioned in first. [FormatNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67905967/14862961)

Comment: Make FormatNumber the wrapper function then, which calls a subfunction. `FormatNumber:{[col;numDecimal] ?[col>0;FormatNumberSub[col;numDecimal];"-",/:FormatNumberSub[abs col;numDecimal]]}` where `FormatNumberSub` contains your original logic

Comment: is there any chance of incorporating code using the string manipulation or else using .Q.fmt or .Q.f

Comment: is there any chance of making changes in the code -> [FormatNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67905967/14862961) instead of  adding new functions or subfunctions?
my requirement is to change in the FormatNumber function logic itself. which calculates for the negative values too

Comment: You could define the sub function (with the core logic) within the FormatNumber function. Then use the if-else line I suggested above, again within the FormatNumber function. It's not ideal but given how strict your requirements are it's all I can offer you

Comment: `prettyPrintNums:{"."sv'@'[;0;{reverse","sv 0N 3#reverse x}]"."vs'neg[0|-[;y]count'[s]-1+s?\:"."]_'s:string x};
q)prettyPrintNums[-0.331;15]`
this throws an error
is there a chance of ammending in the formatnumber function

Comment: It expects a list, not an atom: `prettyPrintNums[(),-0.331;15]`

Comment: yes  `prettyPrintNums[enlist -0.331;15]` is working fine `prettyPrintNums:{"."sv'@'[;0;{reverse","sv 0N 3#reverse x}]"."vs'neg[0|-[;y]count'[s]-1+s?\:"."]_'s:string x};` i want to ammend this in my core logic. how should i do that. by writing a if else condition which only works for negative values

Comment: It already works for both positive and negative, it doesn't need if else

Comment: i want to ammend this `{"."sv'@'[;0;{reverse","sv 0N 3#reverse x}]"."vs'neg[0|-[;y]count'[s]-1+s?\:"."]_'s:string x};` in the core logic which takes inputs as FormatNumber[cols;numDecimals] please see my core logic link ->[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67905967/14862961) or is there a posibilty to edit my core logic  so that it can work for negative stockprice/ values passed to it  as well. i want my core logic to work negative values too

Comment: `FormatNumber:{[col;DecimalPlaces] "."sv'@'[;0;{reverse","sv 0N 3#reverse x}]"."vs'neg[0|-[;DecimalPlaces]count'[s]-1+s?\:"."]_'s:string col};`

Comment: FormatNumber the wrapper function then, which calls a subfunction. `FormatNumber:{[col;numDecimal] ?[col>0;FormatNumberSub[col;numDecimal];"-",/:FormatNumberSub[abs col;numDecimal]]}` where FormatNumberSub in this i want to have upto 15 decimal points. and how to calculate the precision for in this wrapper function